# Java URI simple path

Tags: java, uri

I just discovered the URI method on JAVA.

But I just want this method to show me a simplified path of a string of a string.

The problem is in the following code:

```
public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception {
    URI uri = new URI("/a/./b/../../c/");
    System.out.println("Path =" + uri.getPath());
}
```

When I execute the code it sends me the whole string and not "/ c", which is the result I'm waiting for.

Thanks in advance for your clarifications :)

Comment: No, it's not necessarily. The code HKX is asking for will normalize the URI, not just return the last item in the path.

Comment: thank you for the advice, I will watch ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/net/URI.html),

> Normalization is the process of removing unnecessary "." and ".." segments from the path component of a hierarchical URI. Each "." segment is simply removed. A ".." segment is removed only if it is preceded by a non-".." segment. Normalization has no effect upon opaque URIs.

The `normalize()` method of the URI class should do what you want.

Comment: thank you for the advice, I will watch ;)

Comment: Path path = Paths.get("/home//foo/");System.out.println(path.normalize()); THANK YOU ;)